# Как проверить пароль на сертификат?

Tags: c#

Есть `Em-Marine` карта на которую записан сертификат. Просмотр можно осуществлять через `Etoken PKI client`. Как в c# получить доступ к этому сертификату? Например, просто считать его.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы им подписываете что-то? Тот же крипто-про умеет с этим работать?

Comment: А криптопровайдер есть? В личном хранилище сертификатов , он есть?

Comment: Он отображается только в программе.

Comment: Такс, уточняющий вопрос - вам нужна открытая часть этого сертификата или закрытая?